# php script code executing on page reload within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php

I am initialising the session with the variable name **fromSelectStudentPage** to 1 when the button CONTINUE is clicked.

when i reload the page just for testing the session gets initialised to 1 even without calling the function.

```
<form id="forStudent">
     <button type="button" on-click="onSelectStudent();">CONTINUE</button>
</form>

function onSelectStudent() {
    if(checkStudType()) {
        <?php $_SESSION['fromSelectStudentPage'] = '1'; ?>
        $('form#forStudent').submit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the using of `SESSION`, for store data.

Comment: No attached click event, no call (`on-click`).

Comment: Mixing JS and Php.  $_SESSION['fromSelectStudentPage'] will most likely equal 1, as Php will bypass your JS control structures.  You could use a cookie, with value set with JS